# How to install large software on a different partition

Tags: software-installation, mount, hard-drive, ssd

My system runs from a small (16GB) internal SSD. I'm mounting my `/home` `/swap` and other folders on the main HDD. Now I want to install a large software package (sagemath), whose download size is 700 MB, but installed apparently requires 5.9 GB, so it doesn't fit onto my `/` partition. Can I install the main part of this software on the HDD, rather than on the SSD?

The common advice seems to be to enlarge the root partition, which doesn't work in my case of having different drives.

Is there another solution other than moving my whole system to the (slower) HDD?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Installing the package `sagemath` directly from the repositories seems to require about 6 GB of space on the `/`. However, the program binary can be run directly from any download directory via the command `./sage`, so it is not necessary to install it via the repositories. More info [here](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/installation/binary.html).

Comment: Should I not have posted this answer?

Answer (score 1):

First, take a look [over here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/662597/how-to-combine-separate-partitions-created-by-initial-install-of-kubuntu/662776#662776).

After you've done that you might want to have your partition always mounted. If you don't know how to do that, write a comment and I'll help you.

Comment: Where are you saying I should mount my partition? The answer you link to only tells me how to change folder permissions. I'm wondering if there is a way to install all, or at least a large portion, files of a single software package on a different drive.

Comment: About what kind of package are you talking? About *.deb packages? Because `dpkg` has the switch `--root` which you can use to change where the installed software is stored.

Comment: As I said in the question, I'm looking to install `sagemath` provided by `sagemath-upstream-binary`. I was thinking of installing via a third-party repository, but I guess there are binaries available as well. What does the `--root` switch of `dpkg` do?

Comment: As I said: It installs the deb package in a certain location. So you said `dpkg -i --root /some/custom/location myDebPackage.deb` and myDebPackage.deb will be installed in `som/custom/location`. You should make sure this location is always available (the default location is always available anyway) which is why I asked you whether you know how you do this (by putting it into `/etc/fstab`) or if you need help.